# php variable scope inside a loop in a function

Tags: php, loops, variables, scope

I am wondering is there any way to get the value of a variable, that was defined in a loop inside a function?

Do variables declared in a loop / if-then-else, etc have a limited scope (only inside these blocks)?

here is an example of a function:

```
<?php

function getComments($tabName) {
    $sql = "select
                a.owner,
        a.table_name,
        a.column_name,
        a.data_type,
        a.data_length,
        a.data_precision,
        b.comments
            from 
                all_tab_columns a,
        user_col_comments b
            where 
                a.TABLE_NAME = b.table_name
        and a.COLUMN_NAME = b.column_name
        and a.owner = 'CORE' 
        and a.table_name ='" . $tabName . "'
            order by 
                a.column_id";
    $stid = oci_parse(getConnect(), $sql);

    // runs the query above                   
    oci_execute($stid);
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
        foreach ($row as $column => $entry) {
            // Column name
            if ($column == 'COLUMN_NAME') {
                $output = "this is a column";
            }
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

And here I get the "Undefined variable: output" error.

if I put echo instead the `$output` variable, I get the result.

Is it because the `$output` scope? How can I get the `$output` value in my return?

Comment: Seems that the `$output` variable isn't being set because the if-condition hasn't been satisfied. You should be starting with `$output = '';` at the top of your function to avoid this issue.

Comment: thanks for the hint. However when I try $output = "" at the beginning, I just get an empty result in the output. It just remains unchanged

Comment: Along with @ʰᵈˑ's suggestion of using `$output .= 'this is a column';`, you should still be examining your if-statement, because it's clearly not being satisfied. You need to figure out why that's not happening.

Comment: Maybe change how you save the looped results, perhaps to an array. This way u can see what you are actually returning. Comment out  the "if" line and make `$output` an array. That will send all variables to an array for evaluation

Comment: You're still ignoring the blatantly obvious problem of your if-statement from ever returning true... Or potentially, from the `while` or `foreach` loops never actually executing due to empty SQL results

Comment: Thanks, sjagr. Yes, obviously I have problems with my oci_fetch_array... it fails and as I don't have any condition surely my output is emtpy. I will debug my sql connection logic.

Comment: UPDATE: so the error appeared only when the $tab_name has the lower case. so I added the strtoupper function to the statement and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to satisfy this condition

```
        if ($column == 'COLUMN_NAME') {
            $output = "this is a column";
        }
```

and also u can try to return immediately after ur condition

```
        if ($column == 'COLUMN_NAME') {
            return "this is a column";
        }
```

Comment: if I return immediately after condition, it shows an empty result. It seems it returns only outside the if/then/else and loop blocks

Comment: it was an error in my sql connection/statement logic, as I got "false" while fetching data.